# MySQL CONCAT address into string seperated by commar

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to shorten/easier read the following SQL to concatenate a string.

```
SELECT
   CONCAT(       
    IF(location_address1 != '',
       CONCAT(location_address1, ", "),
       ""
    ),
    IF(location_address2 != '',
       CONCAT(location_address2, ", "),
       ""
    ),
    IF(location_town != '',
       CONCAT(location_town, ", "),
       ""
    ),
    IF(location_region != '',
       CONCAT(location_region, ", "),
       ""
    ),
    IF(location_postcode != '',
       CONCAT(location_postcode, ", "),
       ""
    ),
    c.country_name
   )      
FROM
   countries c      
WHERE
   c.country_id = locations.country_id LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CONCAT_WS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) does not skip empty strings. However, it does skip any NULL values after the separator argument.

[NULLIF(expr1,expr2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif)
Returns NULL if expr1 = expr2 is true, otherwise returns expr1.

SO your query could be:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT_WS(', ', 
       NULLIF(location_address1, ''),
       NULLIF(location_address2, ''),
       NULLIF(location_town, ''), 
       NULLIF(location_region, ''), 
       NULLIF(location_postcode, ''), 
       NULLIF(country_name, '')
  ) AS address
FROM
   countries c      
WHERE
   c.country_id = locations.country_id LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

as per @Xdazz

This Trim Version:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT_WS(', ', 
       NULLIF(Trim(location_address1), ''),
       NULLIF(Trim(location_address2), ''),
       NULLIF(Trim(location_town), ''), 
       NULLIF(Trim(location_region), ''), 
       NULLIF(Trim(location_postcode), ''), 
       NULLIF(Trim(country_name), '')
  ) AS address
FROM
   countries c      
WHERE
   c.country_id = locations.country_id LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function in MySQL as:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',IF(location_address1 = '', NULL, location_address1),
                     IF(location_address2 = '', NULL, location_address2),
                     IF(location_town = '', NULL, location_town),
                     IF(location_region = '', NULL, location_region),
                     IF(location_postcode = '', NULL, location_postcode),
                     c.country_name)  AS str
FROM countries c
WHERE c.country_id = locations.country_id
LIMIT 1;
```

or even simple approach suggested by @CyberDem0n:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',NULLIF(location_address1,''),
                     NULLIF(location_address2,''),
                     NULLIF(location_town,''),
                     NULLIF(location_region,''),
                     NULLIF(location_postcode,''),
                     c.country_name)  AS str
FROM countries c
WHERE c.country_id = locations.country_id
LIMIT 1;
```

but it will be better approach if you can store `NULL` values instead of `blank` values.

Comment: IF(location_address1 = '', NULL, location_address1) can be replaced by NULLIF(location_address1,'')

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   REPLACE(CONCAT(IF(location_address1 != '',
       CONCAT(location_address1, ", "),location_address2,", ",location_town, ", ",location_region,", " , location_postcode , ", " ,c.country_name ),',,',',')    
FROM
   countries c      
WHERE
   c.country_id = locations.country_id LIMIT 1
```

I didn't check the syntax, but my idea is instead of checking each one if it's null or empty, why don't you always concatenate with "," and then replace all ",," with ",".